# How do I calculate prime numbers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For my JavaScript course at school, my assignment is to calculate the first 10 prime numbers.  The instructions specifically say not to use an array to store them or the assignment will result in a zero.  I thought I had my logic worked out, but maybe not.  The code below results in `3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7`  Pretty obvious that it's not correct because 4 and 6 are not prime numbers and also that there are duplicates.  Also, it outputs 12 numbers when the requirement is 10.  What's gone wrong?

```
function primeNumbers(){

            var primeNumbers = []; /* Where the prime numbers are stored */

            for(var dividend = 0; primeNumbers.length <= 10; dividend++){

                for(var divisor = 0; divisor <= dividend; divisor++){

                    if(dividend % divisor > 0){

                        primeNumbers.push(dividend);

                    }

                }

            }

            console.log(primeNumbers.join());

        }
```

Comment: I do not want to use other answers on this site because the work should be my own.

Comment: _The work should be my own_. So why are you asking? If we answer it is still not your own.

Comment: your using an array to store them and you mention that storing them in an array will result in a 0

Comment: i meant as in pre-saving the numbers in an array like primes = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)

Comment: I'm not sure what your algorithm is, but it's probably worth it to check out the [sieve of eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @putvande , to be fair, OP isn't asking for a solution, just for someone to explain "what they did wrong". Which in this case, I guess would be to explain what their code is really doing vis a vis what they want it to be doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem One

Duplicates are caused by the fact that you aren't breaking out of your middle `for` loop:

```
for(var divisor = 0; divisor <= dividend; divisor++){
    if(dividend % divisor > 0){
        primeNumbers.push(dividend);
        // add this line:
        break;
    }
}
```

Also rather than `divisor <= dividend` you may consider some slight optimisations (this way you have to test far fewer possibilities):

```
divisor <= (dividend/2)
```

Or better:

```
divisor <= Math.sqrt(dividend)
```

## Problem Two

**Your Dividend:** Neither `0`, nor `1` is a prime number. It's not cheating to start a test for primality with the first dividend being `2`.

**Your Divisor:** Everything is divisible by `1` and nothing is divisible by `0`. They have nothing to do with primality so exclude them from your for loop and start at `2`.

## Problem Three

Just because `dividend % divisor > 0` is true for one `divisor`, doesn't make `dividend` a prime number: it needs to be true for all `divisor`s. I would add an `isprime` variable outside my for loop and change the condition (to find when the number is certainly not prime):

```
var isprime = true;
for(var divisor = 2; divisor <= root; divisor++){
    if(dividend % divisor == 0){
        isprime = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

```js
function primeNumbers(){
 var primeNumbers = []; /* Where the prime numbers are stored */
 for(var dividend = 2; primeNumbers.length < 10; dividend++){
  var root = Math.sqrt(dividend);
  var isprime = true;
  for(var divisor = 2; divisor <= root; divisor++){
   if(dividend % divisor == 0){
    isprime = false;
    break;
   }
  }
  if (isprime)
    primeNumbers.push(dividend);
 }
 alert(primeNumbers.join());
}

primeNumbers()
```

Comment: So I added the break inside the if statement.  That seemed to prevent duplicates.  I also tried your first suggestion of dividend/2... Those two changes resulted in an output of 5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16

Comment: I'm not getting proper primes with this, [see jsBin](http://jsbin.com/raxeheceba/edit?js,console)

Comment: @Tom try the snippet.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 I have added more to my answer and the snippet works but it does give you the solution (so keep trying before you look at the code)

Comment: @Jan `1` is not prime. `1` will divide any integer so is not a useful test

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations.  I got it working.  Just one question:  the array that is outputted has a length of 11 instead of 10.  Why is this?

Comment: Because it keeps going while `primeNumbers.length <= 10`. That means while the length is below or equal to `10` it will keep adding. If you want the length to be `10`, you should probably stop before that.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Jan is right, the loop runs until that condition is not met. In your case, there are 10 elements and so the condition is satisfied but that means the loop runs again and you end up with eleven elements (which finally breaks out of the loop because `<= 10` evaluates to false).

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 ja, sorry the reason I left it like this is because of the OP (I didn't want to distract by explaining minutiae but: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). I've corrected because it's  a reasonable question and now the comments explain it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting duplicates because you're assuming it's prime every time you've proved it's not divisible by some number rather than waiting for proof for every number. This is the same reason you're getting false positives, i.e. in your function

- `4` wasn't divisible by `3` so it gets added to your list once, even though `4` was divisible by `2`
- `5` wasn't divisible by the numbers `2` to `4`, so you get `3` occurrences of it
- `6` wasn't divisible by the numbers `4` and `5`, so you get `2` occurrences of it, even though it was divisible by `2` and `3`
- `7` wasn't divisible by the numbers `2` to `6`, so you get `5` occurrences of it

To avoid this you need to only add to your list after success of every test, or the another way of thinking about it is to throw the number away after the first failure

---

As you're keeping a catalog of all previous primes you can perform a much faster test by only looking at previous primes, i.e.

1. If a number is co-prime to all primes smaller than it, then it is prime.
2. If a number is co-prime to all numbers smaller than it's square
   root, then it is prime.

So you can test if a number is co-prime to all primes smaller than it's root to find out if it's prime, and you just so happen to have already calculated all of the smaller primes.

```
function primeNumbers() {
    var primeNumbers = [], /* Where the prime numbers are stored */
        candidate = 1, // because I'm ++ing it in the loop we really start at 2
        root,
        i;
    main: while (primeNumbers.length <= 10) {
        ++candidate;
        root = Math.sqrt(candidate);
        for (i = 0; i < primeNumbers.length && primeNumbers[i] <= root; ++i)
            if (candidate % primeNumbers[i] === 0)
                continue main; // this isn't a prime, so skip to next candidate
        // if we reach here then the candidate is prime
        primeNumbers.push(candidate);
    }
    console.log(primeNumbers);
}
primeNumbers(); // logs [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]
```

Comment: This outputs `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`, see [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/hademibeha/edit?js,console)

Comment: @PaulS any reason for `===`?

Comment: @jcuenod In _JavaScript_ I prefer `===` over `==` as `===` doesn't play around with types before checking for equality. This won't have much of an effect in this particular algorithm (`===` is about 10% faster but this is tiny compared to e.g. `%`). The easy way to find out if you have a preference is to ask yourself if you think `[0]` and `false` are equal. `[0] == false; // true` vs `[0] === false; // false`.